# JPA Eclipselink Inheritance: update doesn't work

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem using Eclipselink 2.2.0 to map an inheritance.
Here is my abstract entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Feature extends TenantPossession {

    private FeatureType featureType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public FeatureType getFeatureType() {
        return featureType;
    }

    public void setFeatureType(FeatureType featureType) {
        this.featureType = featureType;
    }
}
```

The sub class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class RecordingFeature extends Feature {
    // here some attributes
}
```

When I save the feature for the first time it works fine. But then when I try to set the feature type and save it, nothing happens.

```
Feature feature = new RecordingFeature();
feature.setType(FeatureType.RECORDING);
feature = featureService.save(feature); // works fine
```

...commit transaction and start another transaction...

```
feature.setType(FeatureType.UNKNOWN);
feature = featureService.save(feature); // seems to work, but type is not set in DB
```

Does it have something to do with the inheritance? I have another cases in code without inheritance that work fine.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but try @MappedSuperclass instead of `@Entity on your abstract class.

Comment: I already thought about that but in this case I would need one service per sub class and searching for all features wouldn't be possible. =/

Comment: why you call again `save(feature)` method? If you would like to change `FeatureType`, just need to call `update(feature)` method, for example. Please, submit `FeatureService` and `Entity` full code.

Comment: It was only an example. The method is called from different places. The only thing inside save method is **return entityManager.merge(entity);**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does save() do?  Ensure you are changing the managed version of the object, not a detached object.

Do you have weaving enabled?  What happens if you disable weaving (change-tracking)?

Comment: save() just calls entityManager.merge(feature). Something I just noticed: if I set any attribute of the sub class, it works. It seems really like a problem on the abstract class.
PS: I am not allowed to set the eclipselink configuration. =(

Comment: Are you using weaving?  Try adding @ChangeTracking(DEFERRED) in your class.  It could be that you are not weaving the superclass, but only the subclass.  Ensure the superclass is included in your list of classes.

Comment: Yes, I'm using weaving but I didn't know this annotation, only the property "eclipselink.weaving.changetracking" in persistence.xml, that I'm not allowed to change. Thanks in advice, I will try that.

Comment: It works!! =) Thanks. But I still don't understand why. What does ChangeTracking do exactly?